# How to make smooth transparency depending on the coordinates of the cursor?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, frontend

How to make such an animation `https://meetwalter.com`?
To change the transparency depending on the position of the cursor?
I made a similar implementation with css, but as I understood on the site it's done through JS clientX / clientY.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Doroshenkomagic/z7mjag2t/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I find something that might help you: https://jsfiddle.net/Doroshenkomagic/z7mjag2t/ and you can take a look at the idea behind it here: https://moul.us/changing-an-elements-opacity-based-on-the-mouses-distance-from-its-center/

Basically:

```
var mouse_x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
var mouse_y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
```

This is one of the key elements: This will constantly track your mouse position. Currently, it's tracking your mouse relative to your top-left corner.

```
var center_x = Math.round(parseInt(element_w) / 2);
var center_y = Math.round(parseInt(element_h) / 2);
```

This is another key element: This will track the center of your image using the preivous code :

```
var element_w = $(this).width();
var element_h = $(this).height();
```

Which detected element's height and width. After that is just a bunch of calculations to discover how far is the mouse when comparing it to the center of the image and applying fade. In your case, you should modify the element's opacity.

You can also find the complete code here: https://github.com/rmmoul/jquery-opacity-by-mouse-location